# Expected way to unit test code in an existing UWP project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, uwp, windows-10-universal

I've been stuck trying to get unit tests up and running. I can create a Universal Unit Test App and run simple tests, but what is the expected and suggested way to integrate this into a larger UWP project?

In Visual Studio, I tried to add a reference of my main project to the unit test project, and then add all the appropriate #include directories. This gets the code compiling appropriately, but every time I try to instantiate an object from my main project, I get the error :

*Unhandled WinRT Exception : Platform::ClassNotRegisteredException
Please check if test is taking reference from an Application. In-process references to applications are not supported in tests.*

What is the expected way to test code in an existing project?
Thank you for your help,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have encountered similar issues unit testing UWP apps this way as well, although in C#.

As a workaround, you could try creating a library (Universal Windows) project which will contain the classes you want to test. Reference this library in the app (to keep the expected behavior in app) and in the `Unit Test App` project (to be able to use the classes in tests).

Comment: I added my classes to a WinRT component project and referenced the code in the main project and the unit test projects. That seemed to do the trick.
Thank you!

Comment: Perfect, glad to hear that it worked :-)!  Happy coding!